# How do I calculate compounding interest with a continously changing interest rate?

Tags: linear-algebra

If the interest rate itself is transformed after each time interval (for example following a parabola, or some other easily calculated trajectory) what would be the equation for this? As an example, imagine an interest rate that is multiplied by .95 each time period. How do I work this into the central equation?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use differential equations. Have a look at http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~nzal/MAS267.dir/contvarint.pdf It is well explained. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: thanks man, looks just right for what I was hoping to find out

Answer (score 0):

Let $x(t)$ be the wealth at time $t$.
The **differential equation** describing the evolution of wealth under **continuous compounding** is $x^{\prime}(t)=r(t)x(t)$ where $r(t)$ is the interest rate at time $t$.

*Remark*.
It is important to note that the interest rate is specified in the same units of time as $t$.
For example, if $t$ is measured in years, then $r(t)$ is a per-annum interest rate.

You can obtain the case of **discrete compounding** by choosing some fixed times $t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{N}$ at which payments occur and discretizing the ODE to obtain a recurrence.
That is,
$$
\frac{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}{t_{n+1}-t_{n}}=r(t_{n})x_{n}.
$$
Given an initial wealth $x_0$ at time $t_0$, you can use the above to obtain the wealth at subsequent times.

Comment: thanks man that explains it well